# A girl wore her hair in bunches, what do you call each of the two parts: a bunch or a side?

Tags: word-request

> [bunches](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bunches) [plural] British English if a girl wears her hair in bunches,
>   she ties it together at each side of her head

[image]

The girl in the picture wore her hair in bunches.

**What do you call each of the two parts: a bunch or a side?**

Comment: Each part is a bunch.

Comment: The bunch is the hairstyle, the side of her head is where the bunch is situated.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, so, can I say "your hair is in bunches" instead of saying "you are wearing your hair in bunches". And, can I say "your hair has 2 / 3 /4 bunches" or "there are 2 / 3 / 4 bunches ON your hair"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "bunch" is simply a collection of individual things pulled together (often held or tied around their circumference).  So you can have "a bunch of flowers" or "a bunch of celery" or "a bunch of hair", etc.

In the example you gave, the girl's hair is "in bunches" implying that it has been pulled together (and wrapped) in multiple separate groups, and each one is a "bunch".

So yes, you can refer to each one of those groups of hair as "a bunch".  If they are on either side, you could also just talk about the two sides, and it would probably mean pretty much the same thing.  However, note that someone's hair being "in bunches" doesn't necessarily mean there's only two of them, or that they are on opposite sides.  Somebody could have lots of little bunches all over their head, etc.  In that case, "a bunch" would not mean the same thing as "a side" of the hair.

Comment: & if, for some reasons, there is only 1 bunch on her head on the right but not on the left for example, then we say "she is wearing her hair in a ponytail", right? (Wiki: a single bunch, regardless of position on the head, is called a ponytail...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigtail)

Comment: alos, can I say "You have a bunch, 3 bunches on your hair"?

Comment: & is it idiomatic to say "she is wearing in bunches / in a ponytail", but wear is an transitive verb and it needs an object right?

Comment: Actually, "bunches" is not very idiomatic in general, I think.  Usually people use specific names for hairstyles:  All the hair pulled together in the back is a "ponytail", one on either side is usually called "pigtails", etc.  I suppose you could say "a ponytail on one side", but if you just say "ponytail" it implies it's centered in the back.  Note that both of these also imply some length of hair (some people might call the hairstyle in your picture "pigtails"; others might not because they are not long enough.  I'm not sure whether there is a common name for that specific style).

Answer (score 0):

I would call them [pigtails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigtail). That may be a AmE/BrE difference, though.